# How to deal with publishing promotion issues Hybris 2105?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have migrated our SAP Hybris from 2011 to 2105.

There are some issues coming while publishing new promotions, which seem to work fine in the lower version.When we publish a promotion(even OOB promotion like in Conditions CMS Site and in Action 10% discount on cart) and when I publish the promotion, I get an error like:

```
   ruleOrderEntryFixedDiscountAction.executeAction(new 
   DefaultDroolsRuleActionContext(variables, kcontext), 
   ["value_uuid":"6e732228-89fe-4f4e-8dea-5235dee2ccd7", 
    "bundleSize":new Integer(4), "bundleSize_uuid":"49803399- 
     53a8-44b6-85cd-35c1b83235d7", "bundleLimit_uuid":"778299c6- 
     75bd-414e-97bb-3e5fe1aa0bf9", "bundleLimit":new Integer(2), 
     "value":new BigDecimal("50")]);
     $groupExecution.trackRuleGroupExecution($config);:
     [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: 
     org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper.$groupExecution()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to some changes in the drools rule engine. This causes an exception during the parsing of older Drools Rule.

To solve this, you can

- Make the content of all drools rules blank, and republish all rules to have correct and active drools rules for all your promotions. Example of a script: You need to disable the interceptors as they might prevent you from changing the rule content

  ```
    import de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.pagedata.PageableData
    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery
    import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorExecutionPolicy;
    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionExecutionBody;
    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService;
    import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;


    int start = 0
    int pageSize = 1000
    int total = pageSize

    final FlexibleSearchQuery searchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("select {PK} from {DroolsRule} ORDER BY {PK}")

    searchQuery.setCount(pageSize)
    searchQuery.setNeedTotal(true)

    while (start < total) {
        searchQuery.setStart(start)
        def searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(searchQuery)

        searchResult.getResult().each {
            final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_TYPES,
                ImmutableSet.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.InterceptorType.PREPARE,InterceptorExecutionPolicy.InterceptorType.VALIDATE));

            sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody() {
                @Override
                public void executeWithoutResult() {
                    it.setRuleContent("");
                    modelService.save(it);
                }
            });
        }

        total = searchResult.getTotalCount()
        start += pageSize
    }

    println "Script has been completed."
  ```

OR

- Remove all `DroolsRule` objects if you no longer need them. Do note that removing these old rules might have impact on existing orders tied to  that Drools rule. The promotion results will still be attached, but it will be hard to tell what promotion triggered that result.

I would advise going for the first option as to not lose any data

**Don't forget to republish your rules after performing either of the steps**

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. The publishing part works fine now, thanks to your comment however promotions do not get applied when product is added to the cart. Any idea how to get started in debugging that? I checked it's setup the same in the previous version of Hybris and works fine.

Comment: Check if the droolsRules for that rule are correctly generated. Could be that you need to publish that specific rule once more. Best way to debug is go to the cart in backoffice and check the promotion resulsts tab if the promo is triggering or not (and use the recalculate at the top). If nothing is showing up, I would suggest to just republish that promo rule again and check again

Comment: We republished the promotion however it still does not apply.

Comment: easiest to debug would be validating that the rule engine is running. => drools modules in backoffice. if you did not customize this, there should only be 1 entry with a green round mark. Next you could create the most basic promotion with no condition and an action like 5% disount and work your way from there

Comment: Thanks Yoni, so promotion does not work when there is any condition.