# Why is the promotion not applied on add to cart in the SAP Commerce Cloud 2105?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are migrating our code to the latest version of SAP Hybris(SAP Commerce Cloud 2105).

The promotions which were working in the lower version do not seem to work in the latest version of SAP Commerce Cloud (2105).

After fixing the issue below:

[How to deal with publishing promotion issues Hybris 2105?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929736/how-to-deal-with-publishing-promotion-issues-hybris-2105)

and republishing it, the promotions still do not seem to work in the latest version(while adding product to the cart)

Is there a change in the architecture? How to go about debugging this?